# SwiftyJSONによるデータ表示コードについて知りたい。

Tags: swift

こんにちは。はじめまして。

xcode 7.3、swift 2.2, cocoapods 1.0.0.beta.2　環境でプロジェクトを進めてきています。
ライブラリが正しくプロパティからデータが取得されないのなぜでしょうか。
（参照：http://webfood.info/swift-rss-reader/）

実装後、メニューバーにはタイトルが表示されるものの、
ウェブデーターが表示されず困っています。

ご参考までにコードを表記します。

TableViewController.swiftのコードはimportとプロパティを追加しています。

```

````
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON


class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var fetchFrom: String?
    var parent: UIViewController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      Alamofire.request(.GET, fetchFrom!).responseJSON { response in
        if let values = response.result.value {
          JSON(values)["responseData"]["feed"]["entries"].forEach {i,value in
            print(value["title"].string!)
            print(value["link"].string!)
          }
        }
      }
    }

```
````

ViewController.swiftのコードは、

```
import UIKit
import PageMenu

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  var pageMenu : CAPSPageMenu?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var controllers : [UIViewController] = []

    var feeds: [Dictionary<String, String>] =
      [
        [
          "link": "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http://menthas.com/top/rss",
          "title": "top"
        ],
        [
          "link": "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http://menthas.com/ruby/rss",
          "title": "ruby"
        ],
        [
          "link": "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http://menthas.com/ios/rss",
          "title": "ios"
        ],
        [
          "link": "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http://menthas.com/infrastructure/rss",
          "title": "infrastructure"
        ],
      ]
    for feed in feeds
    {
      let feedController = TableViewController(nibName: "TableViewController", bundle: nil)
      feedController.parent = self
      feedController.fetchFrom = feed["link"]!
      feedController.title = feed["title"]
      controllers.append(feedController)
    }
```

となっており。

Podfileは下記です。

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!
platform :ios, '9.3'

target 'RSSReaderApp' do
 pod 'PageMenu', '1.2.9'
 pod 'Alamofire', '3.3.1'
 pod 'SwiftyJSON', '2.3.2'

end
```

ビルド後は成功するものの、データが表示されません。
PageMenuはうまく活用されているように思われます。AlamofireかSwiftyJSONに問題があるのだと思います。

RSSデータの取得元は、http://menthas.com/ というサイトです。
APIにうまく通されていないからでしょうか？

こちらから確認できません。
https://github.com/tarky/RssReaderApp/tree/connect-api

何か心当たりがあればご共有ください。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/107533

Comment: 元記事の読み方が間違っているようなので、引き続き作業を進めれそうです。ありがとうございます。